# Like button image not showing in timeline

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I used a Facebook like button on my website, but when I click the "like" button I don't see the image in my timeline. Everything else works fine.

I use this code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/images/fblogo.jpg"/>
```

The two other tags are working fine.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="..."/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You must refer to your image as a fully qualified path (`http://www.yourdomain.com/images/fblogo.jpg`)

be sure you have `prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"` in your `html` tag

also, to test - make sure you're using the [facebook lint tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), so you defeat the caches of facebook.  It also tells you when you have invalid tags and incorrect values for tags.

Comment: hi, thanks. But is still doenst seem to wrok. something else i can do wrong? This is the website: http://mposition.nl/

Answer (score -1):

In got the same error, and solver it by adding `property="og:description"` to the meta description tag, 
this solved my problem but I don´t know if Google likes it....